# Android Game: How often should the server be pinged?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently writing an Android Game. The game has a social part to it, where you can view your friend's scores and compare them to yours.

I'm currently unsure about how often I should update the score of the user. e.g. sending the players' score to the server.

And I'm unsure about how often I should download new data from the server eg. friends scores.

The more I update (making requests to the server) the more expensive this will get, however I don't want it to update to slowly, otherwise the users might get upset.

What is an ideal update time? I was thinking around every 3 minutes?

Comment: -1 + close: too subjective: what's a game session length? How often does the score change? How important is the social part? ...

Comment: @MarvinLabs The Game session length depends on how good you are and the score changes once you've played. However I don't think that information is to relevant.

Comment: Game sessions can vary greatly, independently of whether you're good or not. Chess game, Risk game, platform, shoot'em'up, FPS, ... Identically, score can evolve in different ways (FPS -> +100 each shoot, platform -> Score at the end of the level, ...). You want realtime updates? Updates when level is completed? ... Question is too vague.

Comment: It's a casual game. You are a Space ship flying through space and you destroy the bad guys. You gain points by destroying the bad guys and completing the waves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every session of game send the score to the server & as the above answer said having a button which fetches scores is better. You can do something like View Leaderboard Button , clicking on which should fetch the scores

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it to 10 minutes with additional option for user to fetch the latest scores manually by click of button.

This will avoid regular updates from the server, and also permit user to pull latest updates if he is willing to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider using other techniques to make server notify the clients when there is a change.

For example long polling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple push mechanism as well. Set up a MQTT broker, make your application subscribe to a topic name, whenever a convincing number of users update their scores (say 100 for example) publish the new score list as a message (message limits should be sufficient for such a list) and update your list in the Android app. Note that MQTT is a really good way to achieve this in terms of costs, but setting up this mechanism might be a little tricky if you are not familiar with this concepts.